# ng-repeat does not work when I use it

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

my code as follows:

```
<ons-template id="stockSearch.html">
<ons-page ng-controller="stockSymbolController">
    <ons-toolbar class="DCF">
        <div class="left">
            <ons-back-button style="color:white;"></ons-back-button>
        </div>          
        <div class="center" style="font-size:22px;" >Stock Search  : {{myDCFNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.symbol}}</div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <div class="stockSearchList">
        <div ng-repeat="stockSearch in stocksSearchList">
            <div class="stockSearchOne">
                <div class="stockSearchOneComp">{{stockSearch.company}}</div>
                <div class="stockSearchOneInfo">Symbol: {{stockSearch.symbol}}| Exchange:{{stockSearch.exchange}} </div>                        
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</ons-page>
```

and script.js as follows:

```
module.controller('stockSymbolController', function($scope, $http){
$scope.stocksSearchList = new Object();
var url = "https://www.xxxxx.com/api/public/search_company/"+myDCFNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.symbol;
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        $scope.stocksSearchList = data;
        console.log($scope.stocksSearchList);
    },
});
});
```

but the ng-repeat does not work.when I add the `<div ng-repeat="stockSearch in stocksSearchList">` Even in the middle just display "123" , it would not show.

Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: What does `console.log($scope.stocksSearchList);` show you?

Comment: Why are you using $.ajax instead of $http?

Comment: you aren't opting into the digest cycle!

Comment: console.log($scope.stocksSearchList); show me a json data.

Thank you all for your answer.I solve this problem through use $http.It's my mistake.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Miao yes it will...but because `$ajax` is outside angular, you have to tell angular to update the view....`$http` does that for you

Comment: @Miao yes but what does the data look like (i made an assumption in my answer below)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should use angular's `$http` service not jQuery's `$.ajax` method. From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> The $http service is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP.

So your code should look more like this:

```
module.controller('stockSymbolController', function($scope, $http){
var url = "https://www.xxxxx.com/api/public/search_company/"+myDCFNavigator.getCurrentPage().options.symbol;
$http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) { // success is being deprecated in favour of .then
        $scope.stocksSearchList = response.stocksSearchList; // this should be an array that has nested objects that include properties and values for company, symbol and exchange (see note below)
        console.log($scope.stocksSearchList);
    }, function(error) {
        // do something with the error
    });
});
```

I'm assuming `response` looks like the below with two items in the array:

```
{
    stocksSearchList: [
        {
            company: 'some company',
            symbol: 'some symbol',
            exchange: 'some exchange'
        },
        {
            company: 'some other company',
            symbol: 'some other symbol',
            exchange: 'some other exchange'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ah yep and i included `then` in an answer earlier thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I solve this bug now.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great glad you fixed it

Comment: not quite right on `then()` is promise object ...`scope.stocksSearchList = data.data;`

Comment: yes true it should use the dot notation to get to whatever the property name of the nested object is

Comment: no...that's not my point...the `then` returns a promise objet that has a data property...not same signature as success

Comment: ok yes, status, headers, etc are properties of `response` rather than separate params passed into the success method

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
$scope.stocksSearchList = new Object();
```

Try

```
$scope.stocksSearchList = [];
```

And make sure this returns a list;

Comment: really makes no difference either way since it is being reassigned in callback anyway